# Inception in select

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I got 3 tables like that:

[image]

From which I have to obtain the following pattern:

```
category_name->count(product_id)
...
```

**I have a category_id and I want to have product_id in product table.**

How can I achieve that?

I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.product_id)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_category_30 pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN category_30 c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
OR c.parent_category_id IN(1, 91, 162, 272, 376, 496, 507)
GROUP BY c.category_id
```

Comment: Oh, recursion, I wonder how to solve this...

Comment: I edited the post and sql returns wrong results

Comment: what is your definition of `count(product_id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this working for you?

```
SELECT c.name, count(p.product_id)
FROM category_30 c
JOIN product_category_30 pc
ON c.category_id = pc.category_id
JOIN product p
ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY c.name
```